# How to find absolute min and max of a function over interval?

Tags: calculus

I am literally at my wits end with this one. I understand that you need to set the derivative to 0 to find the critical values, and evaluate them along with the interval endpoints, but I am confused with the whole concept of finding the critical value of something like this, and don't know how to apply that here.

[image: function]

If you could be as specific as possible that would be SO helpful! Thank you :)

Comment: Have you learned the extreme value theorem?

Comment: I understand the concept yes

Comment: The theorem states the location of the extreme points will either be at the endpoints of the interval or at the critical points, and critical points are just locations where $f'(x) = 0$ or undefined. Evaluate the function at the critical point(s) and endpoints and the largest value is the absolute max and the lowest value is the absolute min. Is the issue here you are having trouble computing the derivative?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how to find the critical points, I don't usually have functions like this so the derivative is an issue too..how would I do that? The 5^x3 throws me off. I start off with 4x-??=0 Not sure how that works with the x3 as an exponent! Thanks

Comment: Maybe it will help you if you write $5^x$ as $e^{(\ln 5)x^3}$. Then use the Chain Rule.

Comment: Thanks :) Still trying to figure it out I haven't learned to use ln and e just yet so I have no experience with that

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$f(x)=x^4-5^{x^3}\\
\implies f^\prime(x)=4x^3-3\ln (5)x^25^{x^3}=0\\
\implies 4x^3=3\ln (5)x^25^{x^3}\\
\implies x=0$$
Now,
$$f(0)=-1\qquad f(-5)=625\qquad f(5)=2.3509887016445750159374730744444913556373311135441750430... × 10^{87}$$

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the hint. Still very confused with it all but will try to make sense of it with your example.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading too much into it, but how is this a hint? It's basically the whole problem solved. OP it's your problem not an arbitrary example he constructed.

Comment: I just realized I was reading this problem completely wrong. I had it printed out and it misaligned as though it was 5^x3 when I just noticed the moniter version is 5x^3 yikes! I got the answer right away when I realized. Oops. Thanks for your help everyone :)